# Javascript currency validation doesn't work if clamp button

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, currency-formatting

I want to validate my input according following requirements:

1. value can be from 1.00 to 9999.99
2. value fractional part cannot have more than 2 digits

I have wrote following code:

html:

```
<input id="amount" maxlength="7" type="text" />
```

js:

```
$("#amount").on("keyup", function(){
    var valid = /^[1-9]{1}\d{0,3}(\,\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;

    if(!valid){
        console.log("Invalid input!");
        this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
    }
});
```

But if I clamps '0' it works bad.

Please help to fix.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vY39r/388/)

P.S.

If I press '0' for 3-4 seconds I see

[image]

expected result - all input input be clear

Comment: To allow `0` to be entered you need to change `[1-9]` to `[0-9]`.

Comment: **value can be from 1.00 to 9999.99** thus it cannot be start from 0

Comment: So why do you state that entering `0` is problem?

Comment: If you clamp 0 you will see http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0005/3037/338909/150410/5e7e73cac0.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by 'clamp'? It does not make sense.

Comment: press the '0' button for 3 seconds and release

Comment: Then test a) valid number b) above 0 and empty the box if not, don't just -1 the length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#amount").on("input", function(){
    var valid = /^[1-9]{1}\d{0,3}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;

    if(!valid){
        console.log("Invalid input!");
        this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a2eqrquf/

My Regex isn't really on point, so someone might be able to tidy that up a bit more than I can. But that is working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your regular expresion, so now it's working like you want.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vY39r/391/

```
$("#amount").on("input", function(){
    var valid = /^[0-9]{1}\d{0,3}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;

    if(!valid){
        console.log("Invalid input!");
        this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
    }
});
```

hope it's helps.

Comment: well I have fixed the problem with the 0 @gstackoverflow

Comment: @gstackoverflow let me try to fix it.

Comment: I can input '--2342,'

Comment: is this the solution you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/vY39r/391/ @gstackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

This is what the number input was made for just use the following HTML:

```
<input id="money-input" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="9999.99" step="0.01">
```

If your want to restrict the number of decimals that can be entered you could simply add some JavaScript to round of the number:

```
(function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('money-input');

    input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        this.value = Math.round(this.value * 100) / 100;
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".allownumericwithdecimal").live("keypress keyup ",function (event) {
    var text = $(this).val(); 
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));  



    if(text.indexOf('.') != -1 && event.which==190 )
    {   
        if(text.match("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$")){
        }
        else{
            $(this).val('') ;
        }
    }
     if(text.indexOf('.') == -1 && text.length>7 && (event.which!=190 && event.which !=8 && event.which !=46 && event.which !=110 && event.which !=0)){
         event.preventDefault();
     }
});

$(".allownumericwithdecimal").live("blur",function (event){
    var text = $(this).val(); 
    if((text.indexOf('.') != -1)){  
        if((text.substring(text.indexOf('.'), text.indexOf('.').length).length)>2){
            text = text.toString(); //If it's not already a String
            text = text.slice(0, (text.indexOf("."))+3); //With 3 exposing the hundredths place
            $(this).val(text);
        }
    }
});
```

this is what i use personally

Comment: `live` was removed from jQuery a long time ago.